# Why are UTXO locks stored in memory only?

Tags: bitcoin-core, utxo, listunspent

> **Locks are stored in memory only**. Nodes start with zero locked outputs, and the locked output list
> is always cleared (by virtue of process exit) when a node stops or fails.

https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/lockunspent/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it was added as memory-only filter by Jeff Garzik in PR: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/1861/

> It might be nice to store this in the wallet, but to judge interest and review the interface, this is a useful first step.

Couple of users who care about privacy wanted persistency for locking unspents and created issue: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/14907 but it was closed in May 2020 because of lack of interest.

A pull request has been merged today (26 Sep 2021) to fix this issue by Meshcollider: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/23065. It adds a parameter which can be set to true for saving lock state in database. It's persistent by default in GUI coin control options.