# Use wallet db for locked UTXOs in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, utxo, database, c++, listunspent

Related question: [Why are UTXO locks stored in memory only?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106577/why-are-utxo-locks-stored-in-memory-only)

Sorry this maybe a dumb question for people good with using database in C++ however I am not able to understand what exactly is going wrong or I need to learn more about.

So I made following change in 3 files ([`walletdb.h`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/wallet/wallet.h) [`walletdb.cpp`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/wallet/walletdb.cpp) [`wallet.cpp`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/wallet/wallet.cpp)):

```
diff --git a/src/wallet/walletdb.h b/src/wallet/walletdb.h
index e7b2d7d780c72..a27ffa5e93568 100644
--- a/src/wallet/walletdb.h
+++ b/src/wallet/walletdb.h
@@ -64,6 +64,7 @@ extern const std::string FLAGS;
 extern const std::string HDCHAIN;
 extern const std::string KEY;
 extern const std::string KEYMETA;
+extern const std::string LOCKED_UTXO;
 extern const std::string MASTER_KEY;
 extern const std::string MINVERSION;
 extern const std::string NAME;
@@ -220,6 +221,10 @@ class WalletBatch
     bool WriteTx(const CWalletTx& wtx);
     bool EraseTx(uint256 hash);
 
+    bool LockUTXO(const COutPoint& output);
+    bool UnlockUTXO(const COutPoint& output);
+    bool ListlockedUTXO(std::vector<COutPoint>& vOutpts) const;
+
     bool WriteKeyMetadata(const CKeyMetadata& meta, const CPubKey& pubkey, const bool overwrite);
     bool WriteKey(const CPubKey& vchPubKey, const CPrivKey& vchPrivKey, const CKeyMetadata &keyMeta);
     bool WriteCryptedKey(const CPubKey& vchPubKey, const std::vector<unsigned char>& vchCryptedSecret, const CKeyMetadata &keyMeta);
```

```
diff --git a/src/wallet/walletdb.cpp b/src/wallet/walletdb.cpp
index 3d9248009fdb6..3e442cc12ba58 100644
--- a/src/wallet/walletdb.cpp
+++ b/src/wallet/walletdb.cpp
@@ -40,6 +40,7 @@ const std::string FLAGS{"flags"};
 const std::string HDCHAIN{"hdchain"};
 const std::string KEYMETA{"keymeta"};
 const std::string KEY{"key"};
+const std::string LOCKED_UTXO{"locked_utxo"};
 const std::string MASTER_KEY{"mkey"};
 const std::string MINVERSION{"minversion"};
 const std::string NAME{"name"};
@@ -94,6 +95,22 @@ bool WalletBatch::EraseTx(uint256 hash)
     return EraseIC(std::make_pair(DBKeys::TX, hash));
 }
 
+bool WalletBatch::LockUTXO(const COutPoint& output)
+{
+    return WriteIC(DBKeys::LOCKED_UTXO, output);
+}
+
+bool WalletBatch::UnlockUTXO(const COutPoint& output)
+{
+    return EraseIC(std::make_pair(DBKeys::LOCKED_UTXO, output));
+}
+
+bool WalletBatch::ListlockedUTXO(std::vector<COutPoint>& vOutpts) const
+{
+    return m_batch->Read(DBKeys::LOCKED_UTXO, vOutpts);
+}
+
+
 bool WalletBatch::WriteKeyMetadata(const CKeyMetadata& meta, const CPubKey& pubkey, const bool overwrite)
 {
     return WriteIC(std::make_pair(DBKeys::KEYMETA, pubkey), meta, overwrite);
```

```
diff --git a/src/wallet/wallet.cpp b/src/wallet/wallet.cpp
index 9986a02fc1011..af9ddf3c47d2f 100644
--- a/src/wallet/wallet.cpp
+++ b/src/wallet/wallet.cpp
@@ -2233,18 +2233,37 @@ bool CWallet::DisplayAddress(const CTxDestination& dest)
 #endif
 }
 
-void CWallet::LockCoin(const COutPoint& output)
+
+/*void CWallet::LockCoin(const COutPoint& output)
 {
     AssertLockHeld(cs_wallet);
     setLockedCoins.insert(output);
+}*/
+
+void CWallet::LockCoin(const COutPoint& output)
+{
+
+        WalletBatch batch(GetDatabase());
+        batch.LockUTXO(output);
+
+
+
+
 }
 
-void CWallet::UnlockCoin(const COutPoint& output)
+/*void CWallet::UnlockCoin(const COutPoint& output)
 {
     AssertLockHeld(cs_wallet);
     setLockedCoins.erase(output);
+}*/
+
+void CWallet::UnlockCoin(const COutPoint& output)
+{
+    WalletBatch batch(GetDatabase());
+    batch.UnlockUTXO(output);
 }
 
+
 void CWallet::UnlockAllCoins()
 {
     AssertLockHeld(cs_wallet);
@@ -2259,7 +2278,8 @@ bool CWallet::IsLockedCoin(uint256 hash, unsigned int n) const
     return (setLockedCoins.count(outpt) > 0);
 }
 
-void CWallet::ListLockedCoins(std::vector<COutPoint>& vOutpts) const
+
+/*void CWallet::ListLockedCoins(std::vector<COutPoint>& vOutpts) const
 {
     AssertLockHeld(cs_wallet);
     for (std::set<COutPoint>::iterator it = setLockedCoins.begin();
@@ -2268,7 +2288,16 @@ void CWallet::ListLockedCoins(std::vector<COutPoint>& vOutpts) const
         vOutpts.push_back(outpt);
     }
 }
+*/
 
+void CWallet::ListLockedCoins(std::vector<COutPoint>& vOutpts) const
+{
+    WalletBatch batch(GetDatabase());
+    batch.ListlockedUTXO(vOutpts);
+
+
+
+}
 /** @} */ // end of Actions
 
 void CWallet::GetKeyBirthTimes(std::map<CKeyID, int64_t>& mapKeyBirth) const {
```

This doesn't work as expected and return wrong txid, vout:

[image: terminal-output]

Comment: Your Write functionality stores for key LOCKED_UTXO a single COutPoint, and every further lock will overwrite the same key. When reading, you're deserializing into a vector of COutPoints, which doesn't match what you're writing. A vector is not the same as a single element. You probably want to store all locked utxos in separate keys.

Comment: PR from meshcollider: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/23065